# How to remove word from text file containing X number of characters?

Tags: awk, sed, textedit

I found quiet few posts here suggesting solutions using `awk` and `sed`, but none of them seems to do the job. Either the whole line is being removed, or nothing at all is removed. I'm also not command line wizzard and my knowledge is kind of limited, so I decided to ask for help here. It doesnt matter the solution, whether is `awk`, `grep`, `sed`... I honestly can't make any difference in this case, so it will be whatever you feel it's beset in this case.

What I have is several files with few million lines, and the files/lines look something like this:

```
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
50somethingcharactergibberish shortrword
```

And this goes for several million lines. What I need to do, is to remove the 50somethingcharactergibberish and leave only the shortword. The problem also is that there is no pattern, the long word in question sometimes starts with letter, and sometimes with number. So I assume I'll have to count the characters eventually.

Comment: Are there always only two such words in all the lines in the file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Inian. Yes, there are only tho words on each line. There is one space between the firs and the second word. Otherwise the same thing million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most minimal `awk` that could work for you is something like:-

```
awk '!($1="")' million-line-file
```

Comment: Thank you very much Inian! This was exactly what I was looking for :) I accepted your answed, but it is not marked because I have low reputation. But as I said, this was the solution I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @mrBlob: read through [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanks Inian, apparently I voted instead of accepting it. It's accepted now! :)

Answer (score 0):

awk is overkill for this try `cut`

```
cut -f2 -d ' ' 2col.list > 2ndcol.list
```

says `cut` the second field `-f2` considering a space to be field delimiter `-d ' '`  for every row in the input file and redirect that second field into the output file